# complete with missing data

Tags: r, tidyr

Say I had this type of data and I wanted to expand it to use the combinations of `item_id` and `group` not present. I can use `complete` from {tidyr} for that. That's great.

```r
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
df <- tibble(
  group = c(1:2),
  item_id = c(1:2),
  value1 = c(1, 2)
)
df
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   group item_id value1
#>   <int>   <int>  <dbl>
#> 1     1       1      1
#> 2     2       2      2


complete(df, group, nesting(item_id))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   group item_id value1
#>   <int>   <int>  <dbl>
#> 1     1       1      1
#> 2     1       2     NA
#> 3     2       1     NA
#> 4     2       2      2
```

What is, though, I was absolutely certain that there was also a `3` in item_id and that even though it is missing, it *should* be there. Is there anyway to manually specify the levels of a variable that is "completed"? The desired output is:

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  group item_id value1
  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1       1      1
2     1       2     NA
3     1       3     NA
4     2       1     NA
5     2       2      2
6     2       3     NA
```

But I just can't seem to see how to manually specify those levels?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `complete(df, group, item_id = 1:3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're sure the levels of `item_id` are "1:3" one potential option is to mutate `item_id` to suit, e.g.

```r
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- tibble(
  group = c(1:2),
  item_id = c(1:2),
  value1 = c(1, 2)
)

df %>%
  mutate(item_id = factor(item_id,
                          levels = c(1:3))) %>%
  complete(group, item_id)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   group item_id value1
#>   <int> <fct>    <dbl>
#> 1     1 1            1
#> 2     1 2           NA
#> 3     1 3           NA
#> 4     2 1           NA
#> 5     2 2            2
#> 6     2 3           NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: oh factors! brilliant.